# insertSublayer will hide cells in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, ios7

This code works in iOS7, but when running in iOS6 simulator the cells who should be above the sublayer will instead be below them.

```
bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer gradientFromColor:COLOR_MID_GRADIENT to:COLOR_GRADIENT];
CGRect bottom = self.view.bounds;
bottom.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height-GRADIENT_HEIGHT;
bottom.size.height = GRADIENT_HEIGHT;
bgLayer.frame = bottom;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:1];
```

What it does is to put a gradient-layer at the bottom of a view with a tableview.

However, the cells in the rect of the gradient will be hidden behind it!

I tried to change the index but it doesnt do anything. Also, insertSublayer: below: doesn't work either.

What am I missing? How to put the layer below the table view cells?

Thanks.

Comment: How many layers already exist before the insert in both iOS 6 and iOS 7?

Comment: one, I've inserted one indentical at the top.

Comment: How do you know that?  (just to be clear I'm asking how many **already exist** in the layer **before** your insert).

Comment: How do I even find out? I've not worked with layers in iOS before.

Comment: Logging.  Also log the `zPosition` of the existing layers. Something like:  `NSArray *sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers; for (CALayer *layer in sublayers) { NSLog(@"layer zPosition=%f", layer.zPosition); }`

Comment: Hmm, they're all 0.0000! Can I manipulate this manually?

Comment: No, just set the `zPosition` of your background layer to a negative value (`-100.0f`, for example).

Comment: I've set them to -1.0 now, and the logging is fine. Though the layer itself is not shown now. :/

Comment: OK cool.  Is the existing layer transparent?  Also how does it behave on an iOS 6 device, rather than the simulator?

Comment: I cannot try it on iOS6-device unfortunately. What I have now when I nil-ed the background view is a correct gradient at top where no cells are present. But the bottom gradient is "cut off" at the cell start. It's like they are conflicting and now the Cell got higher priority.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow.  I'm out of ideas anyway.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess it could be a simulator bug. Its weird!

Comment: After sleeping on the problem I've managed to get it working with the zPosition. Though I have to run the layer-code in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear for iOS6. Don't ask me why, I guess it has to do with the rendering of the cells happening after viewWillAppear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to trojanfoe I got pointed in the right direction.

I've managed to get it working with manually changing the zPosition for the conflicting layers. Though I have to run the add layer-code in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear for iOS6. Don't ask me why, I guess it has to do with the rendering of the cells happening after viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

You mean below, as in "behind"? If so, set the backgroundView of the tableview , and modify it as you see fit. (layers, subvies etc) and it will always appear behind the cells

Comment: Thanks, I was adding layers to the view itself instead of the backgroundView of the tableView.

Comment: NO! The background view is static and does not follow the table view when scrolling. This will mean that my gradients are in a static position. How to add actual layers to the tableview? :/

Comment: True, it is static. but the view behind the tableview is also static. If you want it to scroll with your tableview you need to create a clever solution for that. I wouldn't add a view directly to the tableview itself (who knows how the tableview manages it's subviews)

Comment: The scrolling works when i put the layers in as I do above. It's only for iOS6 when I get problems with the layers overriding eachother.

Comment: @Spoek And my hint about `zPosition` hasn't sparked anything for you?

Comment: whats the view hierarchy? 
e.g. view->tableview,

Also the zPosition hint makes sense.

Comment: actually it is view->containerview->view->tableview, but the containerview shouldn't even matter.